# TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined Passpor error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I'm making a login and register page. I'm using passport to do the authentication. I'm using mongosse too. Everything is working fine, however I do not know why user.name is undefined. I tried every single solution that I found on stack related with this problem, but it does not match.

router.js

```
    require('dotenv').config()
}

const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const User = require('../models/user');
const passport = require('passport');
const initializePassport = require('./passport-config')
const flash = require('express-flash')
const session = require('express-session');
const { JsonWebTokenError } = require('jsonwebtoken');
require('./db/mongoose');



const app = express();

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const publicDirectoryPath = path.join(__dirname, '../public');
const viewsPath = path.join(__dirname, '../views');

initializePassport(
    passport,
    async(email)=>await User.findOne({email: email}),
    async(id)=>await User.findById(id).then(console.log())
)


app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', viewsPath);


app.use(express.static(publicDirectoryPath));
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(flash());
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session())



app.use(session({
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
}));

app.get('/registration',(req, res) => {
    res.render('registration.ejs');
})

app.get('/login',(req, res) => {
    res.render('login.ejs')
})

app.get('/menu',(req, res) => {
    res.render('menu.ejs', { name: req.user.name })
})

app.post('/registration', async(req, res) => {
    try{
        const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10);
        
        const newUser = new User({
            name: req.body.name,
            email: req.body.email,
            password: hashedPassword
        });

        newUser.save();

        res.redirect('/login');        

    } catch{
        res.redirect('/registration')
    }
})


app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', {
    successRedirect: '/menu',
    failureRedirect: '/login',
    failureFlash: true,
}))


app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('Server is on port 3000');
})
```

passport-config.js

```
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')

function initialize(passport, getUserByEmail, getUserById){
    const authenticateUser = async (email, password, done)=>{
        const user = await getUserByEmail(email)

        if(user == null){
            return done(null, false, {message: 'No existe un usuario con ese email'})
        }


        try{
            
            const matchPassword = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)

            if(matchPassword){
                return done(null, user)
            }else{
                return done(null, false, {message: 'Constraseña Incorrecta'})
            }
        }catch(e){
            return done(e);
        }
    }

    passport.use(new LocalStrategy({usernameField: 'email'}, authenticateUser))
    passport.serializeUser((user,done)=> done(null, user.id))
    passport.deserializeUser((id,done)=> {
        return done(null, getUserById(id))})

}

module.exports = initialize
```

The error is the following:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
> at C:\Users\Miguel\Desktop\RestaurantControl\src\router.js:58:45
> at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Miguel\Desktop\RestaurantControl\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
> at next (C:\Users\Miguel\Desktop\RestaurantControl\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
> at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\Miguel\Desktop\RestaurantControl\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
> at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Miguel\Desktop\RestaurantControl\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
> at C:\Users\Miguel\Desktop\RestaurantControl\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
> at Function.process_params (C:\Users\Miguel\Desktop\RestaurantControl\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
> at next (C:\Users\Miguel\Desktop\RestaurantControl\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
> at Immediate._onImmediate (C:\Users\Miguel\Desktop\RestaurantControl\node_modules\express-session\index.js:502:7)
> at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:460:21)

Comment: May you do some debugging? There’s a couple times name is used. One of those is happening when the object is undefined. Consider tracking that down.

Comment: user.name isn't undefined... `user` is undefined. So you should see why you aren't getting a user.

Comment: @Diesel  the library "Passport" that I'm using put the data from "the form of the login page to an object "user"

Comment: @evolutionxbox I will

Comment: if the error is on the line `req.user.name`, request exists. But it isn't returning a user property. That's where your problem is. I don't know why req isn't giving a user.

Comment: @Diesel That's exactly the problem. I want to figure out why that's not returning the user property. I've been crazy the whole day with this bug.

Comment: Have you looked at the request object to see what it has on it?

Comment: @Diesel nothing special. Just an the same thing

Answer (score 0):

```
router.get('/', checkAuthorization, async (req, res) => {
    const result = await req.user
    res.render('index.ejs', data = { name: result.name}) })
```

`req.user` will return promise if you are using passport module. `await req.user` and `async function`. I had the same issue and came up with this solution.